# How to try out new 'Search Builder'?

Tags: search-builder

I understand from other posts that the new Search Builder is included in 5.29 but is hidden.  I'd like to give it a try - how can I access it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note if you install from a tar file the extension is not available until 5.30. Git/composer/buildkit installs have it in 5.29.

Also the styling on the search page is messy until 5.31, and before then has some other issues.

**UPDATE**: As of 2020-10-06, it's now visible in the UI as an installable extension called "Search Kit" that comes included with 5.31+. You just install it like any other extension. For earlier than 5.31 see below.

---

## Using user interface

1. In civi go to the menu for support - developer - api3 explorer.
2. Choose Extension with action Install.
3. For parameter pick Extension Key, and for the value put org.civicrm.search.
4. At the bottom click Execute.
5. Then the Search menu will have a new option at the bottom.

## Using command line

1. `cv api Extension.install keys="org.civicrm.search"`

Comment: can this be done using cv?

Comment: Is there anything that can't be done with cv? He he - I'll update answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me with 5.29.1 - I got the following:     {
    "is_error": 1,
    "error_message": "Unknown extension: org.civicrm.search"
}

Comment: I did it with master. I'm not sure exactly what version it was fully available. You can try it on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org though.

Comment: @AndyClark I tried it with 5.29.1 and it worked ok to install. The theme is off when you visit the search page, and it looks like that's fixed in 5.31.

Comment: quite a few things are fixed in 5.31 compared to 5.29

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is. Git has it in 5.29, but tarballs don't have it until 5.30.

Comment: Just installed 5.30 from a tarball and the install worked - thanks!